# nginx connect() failed (110: Connection timed out)

Tags: mysql, nginx, centos, reverse-proxy

I know that, this question has been asked multiple times on different forums, but still I can not manage to find a solution, which solves my problem... The situation: We have a nginx, php-fpm and MySQL stack on a server. The server sits behind a nginx reverse proxy. The problem is that on the upstream server there are clean error logs and on the reverse proxy I am getting multiple messages

> connect() failed (110: Connection timed out) while connecting to >upstream, client: ++++++++++, server: domain.com, request: "GET >/files/imagecache/FrontBullet/blog1/dknasda.jpg HTTP/1.1", upstream: >"http://192.168.158.142:80/files/imagecache/FrontBullet/blog1/dknasda.jpg>", host: "somedomain.com"

For some reason this error occurs every 1-5 minutes for different resources or files.

My nginx config on the reverse proxy is the following one :

```
    user ++++;
worker_processes 3;
error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections 1024;
    use epoll;
}

http {
    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                  '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                  '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile            on;
    tcp_nopush          on;
    tcp_nodelay         on;
    keepalive_timeout   60s; #keeps the connection open with the client; MS default is 60.
    types_hash_max_size 2048;

    include             /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type        application/octet-stream;

    gzip on; 
    gzip_http_version 1.1; 
    gzip_vary on; 
    gzip_comp_level 6; 
    gzip_proxied any; 
    gzip_types text/plain  text/css application/json application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript application/javascript text/x-js; 
    gzip_buffers 16 8k; 
    gzip_disable "MSIE [1-6]\.(?!.*SV1)";

    upstream main_upstream {

        server 192.168.158.142:80 max_fails=3  fail_timeout=60s;  #       New Server. Sent to 192.168.90
#   server 192.168.158.143:80;   #       HSB
    keepalive 32;
    }

server {
    listen       80 default_server;
    listen       [::]:80 default_server;
    server_name  domain.com;

    location / {
        proxy_buffers 32 32k;
        proxy_buffer_size 64k;
        proxy_pass http://main_upstream;
        proxy_set_header    Host $host;
        proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-By $server_addr:$server_port;
            proxy_set_header    X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_connect_timeout       600s;
        proxy_send_timeout          600s;
        proxy_read_timeout          600s;
        send_timeout                600s;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Connection "";
        client_max_body_size                            32M;
        client_body_buffer_size                         512k;
    }
    error_page 404 /404.html;
        location = /40x.html {
    }

    error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
    }
}
```

Any Idea why is this happening? I am using centos 7.1 abd nginx 1.6.3

Thanks in advance,
Todor

Comment: It's not your nginx problem... it's most probably your upstream (Apache?) that is crashing and restarting every few minutes (or blocking nginx ip)

Comment: The upstream is again nginx and the error log of the upstream is clear. I would appreciate if you have any other ideas or point me in some direction how to check it.

Comment: Indeed your upstream error is clear. It's telling you that nginx requested for something, and that something didn't reply back to nginx. It's not a nginx problem, it's whatever server you have listening on those ip's listed on your upstream block. Are you running nginx on the other servers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally found the reason and it has been clean for hours now. It turned out that there were 2 overlapping problems. The first one was the kernel dropping requests after the queue is full. Here is a nice manual about tuning the kernel linux kernel parameters - https://www.nginx.com/blog/tuning-nginx/

After the problems started we migrated the site to a new server and used DHCP to assign IP address - BIG MISTAKE. Every hour or so the dhcp restarted the network Interface. Examining the entire system log I noticed that the IP  of the network interface is reassigned on regular intervals. Those intervals coincided with the bursts of errors in the log. So the solution was to go back to static IPs.

Answer (score 0):

You have a upstream block like this:

```
upstream main_upstream {
    server 192.168.158.142:80 max_fails=3  fail_timeout=60s;  # New Server. Sent to 192.168.90
#   server 192.168.158.143:80;   #       HSB
    keepalive 32;
    }
```

The first line fetches requests from 192.168.158.142:80 and stop trying after 3 fails for 60 seconds.
The second line is commented out, so it doesn't work.
Also there are other ip's listed on your other comments, which obviously won't work.

Assuming you want to fetch requests from `192.168.158.142:80` and failover to another ip `192.168.158.143:80` if it fails, this is how you do it:

```
upstream main_upstream {
        keepalive 30;
        server 192.168.158.142:80;        # main server
        server 192.168.158.143:80 backup; # failover
}
```

Or if you want to distribute the load evenly in a round robin style:

```
upstream main_upstream {
        keepalive 30;
        server 192.168.158.142:80; # server 1
        server 192.168.158.143:80; # server 2
}
```

In both cases, make sure you can access both `192.168.158.142:80` and `192.168.158.143:80`

Also bear in mind that you're using keepalive, meanning that if your backend servers are set to limit requests in any way, they might start refusing to serve requests to your frontend nginx (I will assume this is your load balancer).

Comment: Hi,

first of all thank you for the reply.
To your second post: We need only one server - 192.168.158.142 . The other one is a HotStandBy for the maintenance windows when we shut down the primary.

The upstream server is indeed again nginx acting as a web server with php-fpm. The question is why did`t it reply to the requests from the reverse proxy... so far I am clueless since the error logs of the upstream server are clear. I just manually checked and most of the requested resources are on the server(No 404s) and they were served correctly by the rproxy, those being static as well dynamic..

Comment: Where are you reading these `110: Connection timed out` logs from? Is it on the load balancer or the backend server? If it's on the load balancer (frontend) then your backend is not replying to the reverse proxy. If you're seeing these logs on your backend server, it means php is not replying to your backend server and therefore, could never reply to your frontend. You can post both nginx.conf files here (for both front and back server) and we might see if something is off. Also add your server and location blocks if on separate files.

Comment: The errors are on the load balancer. For some still unknown reason every 20 minutes the backend server decides not to respond to the get requests from the frontend. Those are the backend config files. They are pasted together for conviniece http://pastebin.com/DsH0vbtt  . I did MariaDB tweaking, php tweaking, increased the open files limit, increased the open port limits etc. nothing works. I am starting to think that the problem is in the php scripts. Something seems to be rendering the backend nginx unresponsive. Further the backend error log is clear. Nothing in there. Thanks in advance

Comment: I forgot to mention that those timeouts occur with static as well with dynamic  resources. It is even stranger, because they seem to have appeared around the 16.02  and there were no updates on the system or changes of any kind. As far as I was notified there were just some minor static code(HTML) changes in the template of the website which is hosted.

Comment: OK, I see several things that should not be configured this way, so let me ask you a few things... How much RAM do you have, what CPU do you have and how many requests (dynamic + static) per second do you expect to serve from your backend? Why do you have 3 uptream servers `server 127.0.0.1:9000; server 127.0.0.1:9001; server 127.0.0.1:9002;` ? Are those servers different versions or php or something? Nginx for drupal should look like this: https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/recipes/drupal/

Comment: Hi, The ram is 7.15 GB. There are 4 CPU cores and I expect about 1,2k requests/sececond. Regarding the php-fpm upstream - there are 3 upstreams in case one of them hangs... One more thing the nginx drupal config is config for a d5 system(a legacy one). This config was running for the last 2 years and at some point 15 days ago it started popping errors whitchout any changes or updates..

Comment: Let me just add that you might want to look into hhvm with failover to php 5.6 on your upstream server. I was going to tell you about the kernel tweaks, but glad you found on your own. Also, you should at least these settings to this values: `worker_processes  4;  worker_connections  50000;` There's no much benefit above 4 workers but there is with the worker connections (less respawn). `worker_rlimit_nofile    750000;` for high concurrency is also not a bad idea, (provided you change your security OS files to allow 999999).